# Using @SuppressWarnings within method generates compile error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have the following code block:

```
     final Map<String, Double> map;
            if (cond) {
                int currency = 44;
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                map = (Map<String, Double>)objectA.get();
            }else {
                map= ....}
```

`get()` method of `objectA` returns a raw `HashMap`(I know that would be nice to use generics there and my problem would be solved, but i cannot change the code from that class). If I remove  `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` line, obviously I get an `TypeSafety` warning. But when I add supress warning in line that is right bellow assignment, I get the following error :

```
map cannot be resoved to a type!
```

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: What kind of type is objectA? And btw you defined map as final, so you cannot assign values later to this var.

Comment: Map is final, but I assing a value for it on both branches, so thats not a problem. ObjectA type is a usual class, nothing special.

Comment: Is that the actual error? It seems to have a typo.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler thinks that `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is an expression and there's no terminal operator `;`. However, if you add it, the expression is invalid.

You have to annotate the method *or* use the annotation before the variable definition:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public void method() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final Map<String, Double> map;
    if (cond) {
        int currency = 44;
        map = (Map<String, Double>)objectA.get();
    }
}
```

Note that the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) suggests that:

> As a matter of style, programmers should always use this annotation on the most deeply nested element where it is effective.

Comment: I hardly ever manually type `@SuppressWarnings`. And the IDE knows where to place them.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a [Local Variable Declaration *Statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) can be annotated. Other types of *statements* can not.

Your code shows an [expression statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) (an assignment expression):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
map = (Map<String, Double>)objectA.get();
```

This cannot be annotated. You probably started with a Local Variable Declaration Statement like below and then moved the type `Map<String, Double>` outside the `if` statement:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Double> map = (Map<String, Double>)objectA.get();
```

The Java parser will actually expect a Local Variable Declaration Statement, if it sees an annotation within a method (or a type declaration, but let's ignore that now).
Such a statement always starts with a type, and that's what the error is telling you: `map` is not a valid type.

(Note that if `map` were a valid type, it would then complain that you didn't specify an identifier before the `=`.)